# Ionic Offline MAP

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am working on a hybrid mobile app using ionic. I have developed all feature of app but One of the features I need is offline google map. I want to get lattitude and longitude of user when there was no internet and after reaching in interent zone it threw data using web API.
   Is there a way how to do it? I want it for Android and Ios both.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, if there is no network you want to still get the user location, store it and send it once the network is available again? What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes i want to get user current location when he have no internet . Tracking can display like Google map tracking .When we have started tracking to my location to other it can work without internet ,I checked some post of leaflet js but didn't implement it. I can store data using sqlite or pouch db but main concern to get the data without interent ,

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is only getting the user location, that can be done with no need for internet. Instead, you can use GPS to get the location, and that can be specified by some options when you are getting the location, depending on what library you are using.